# How does Knex await execute a database query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, async-await, knex.js

I'm trying to understand how the `await` keyword is being used in KNEX. Take the following example:

```
knex.schema.createTable( ... );
```

this will return `this` which is an instance of SchemaBuilder. It will not execute the create table query in the database. However if I stick and `await` in front of it.

```
await knex.schema.createTable( ... );
```

This will now execute the create query in the database.

My understanding is that `await` is used to wait for a promise resolution but in this case it feels like something else is going on because not `await`ing the function doesn't return a promise.

How does this work?

Comment: This was my understanding but if I don't `await` the function call it definitely doesn't create the table in the database. Compared with if I do use `await` it will execute the query and the table will appear in the database.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The former expression just creates a SchemaBuilder, the latter expression calls the SchemaBuilder's `.then()` method.

Comment: @Bergi - Why, *why* didn't I think of a custom thenable??

Comment: @Bergi you are right! I didn't realise you could set up a then prototype that would be called when you use `await`. `await fn()` is just simply syntax sugar for `fn().then()`. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know how `knex` only makes requests when you write `await` in front of the construct, then here.

Under the hood, `knex` uses a `pattern` that returns an object with a `then` field.

```js
const asyncFunction = (delay) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve(delay);
    }, delay);
  })
}

const builder = (delay) => {
  return {
    then: async (resolve) => {
      const result = await asyncFunction(delay);
      return resolve(result);
    }
  }
}

const main = async () => {
  const array = [];
  for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
    array.push(builder(i));
  }
  console.log('array', array);
  console.log('array[0]', array[0]);
  console.log('await array[0]', await array[0]);
  console.log('Promise.all for array', await Promise.all(array));
}

main();
```

The result of this execution will be the following output to the console

```js
array [
  { then: [AsyncFunction: then] },
  { then: [AsyncFunction: then] },
  { then: [AsyncFunction: then] },
  { then: [AsyncFunction: then] },
  { then: [AsyncFunction: then] },
  { then: [AsyncFunction: then] },
  { then: [AsyncFunction: then] },
  { then: [AsyncFunction: then] },
  { then: [AsyncFunction: then] },
  { then: [AsyncFunction: then] }
]
array[0] { then: [AsyncFunction: then] }
await array[0] 0
Promise.all for array [
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
  5, 6, 7, 8, 9
]
```

As you can see, the code inside the `then` function will not be called until the await keyword or other ways of waiting for `Promise` are used.

Comment: Don't forget the second parameter to `then`. Also I would recommend not to make `then` an `async function` to avoid weird handling of rejections. Just make `{ then(...args) { return asyncFunction().then(...args); } }`.